# Как nodejs делает http запросы?

Tags: node.js

Как NodeJS делает http запросы асинхронно, если nodejs работает в один поток? При получении данных с сервера должно же блокироваться все

Comment: Объяснять долго можно. Почитайте про `Event loop`. Это не самая большая тема про ноду, но важная.

Comment: https://youtu.be/zphcsoSJMvM потому что nodejs работает не совсем в один поток

Answer (score 0):

Если не влазить в техническую реализацию, то на верхнем уровне абстракции это выглядит как очередь. Асинхронно - значит просто то, что асинхронный код выполняется после синхронного тогда, когда готов/должен выполниться. Если перед ним в очереди выполняется другой код, то ждет.